# NullPtrException Java using enum in Map

Tags: java

I was trying an alternate way of doing some code I already have that I find unelegant and I met this exception. I don't really understand what's happening, I'm still very new to Java.

I'm sorry if there is a bit much code but I don't think I can cut much more. The exception is raised on the first line of `Initialize()`.

Here is the exact error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   simulationia.CritterInfo.Initialize(Critter.java:35)  at
>   simulationia.SimulationIA.main(SimulationIA.java:21)

Line 35 is the first line of `Initialize()`. Line 21 of SimulationIA is the call to `Initialize()`.

```
// Critter.java
class CritterInfo { 
    static private Map<Object, String> enum_desc;

    public enum CRITTER_TYPE { CT_HERBIVORE, CT_CARNIVORE }
    public enum CRITTER_STATE { CS_FULL, CS_HUNGRY, CS_STARVING, CS_DEAD }

    /* ... */

    static void Initialize() {
        enum_desc.put((Object)CRITTER_TYPE.CT_HERBIVORE,    "Herbivore");
        enum_desc.put((Object)CRITTER_TYPE.CT_CARNIVORE,    "Carnivore");
        enum_desc.put((Object)CRITTER_STATE.CS_FULL,        "Full");
        enum_desc.put((Object)CRITTER_STATE.CS_HUNGRY,      "Hungry");
        enum_desc.put((Object)CRITTER_STATE.CS_STARVING,    "Starving");
        enum_desc.put((Object)CRITTER_STATE.CS_DEAD,        "Dead");
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

The other file...

```
// SimulationIA.java
public class SimulationIA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* ... */

        CritterInfo.Initialize();

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to have one single map to hold all enum values without caring about its type and having to check with `instanceof`. Maybe this is just not doable.

Edit: I think this may have to do with the fact that I do not use actual objects, only values of the enum hence it complaining about null pointer. Is that right ? How would I go around this ?

Comment: To be blunt, that's terrible design. If you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, we can help you improve it.

Comment: Sure. I don't know any better. Basically I just want to be able to have a text description matched to every enum value. This is not really an issue in what I am trying to do. I'm just trying to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never create the Map, so `put` is called on `null`.

You should do something like (for example):

```
static private Map<Object, String> enum_desc = new HashMap<Object, String>();
```

Comment: Dumb mistake ! I also notice that I use an abstract type instead of a instantiable type.

Comment: @Alexandre Declaring the variable using an abstract type is usually a good idea.

Comment: Giving checkmark because this solves the problem I listed (even though I will take advice from other posts on how to do what I want to achieve more properly).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, "I just want to be able to have a text description matched to every enum value":

You can take advantage of Java's enums:

```
public enum Enum {

    DOG("Dogs are cool"),
    CAT("Dogs are better"),
    GOAT("Free milk");

    private final String desc;

    private Enum(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }    

}
```

Comment: Nifty. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with basic...

```
public enum CRITTER_TYPE { CT_HERBIVORE, CT_CARNIVORE }
public enum CRITTER_STATE { CS_FULL, CS_HUNGRY, CS_STARVING, CS_DEAD }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (CRITTER_TYPE type : CRITTER_TYPE.values()) {
        System.out.println(type);
    }
}
```

Will output

```
CT_HERBIVORE
CT_CARNIVORE
```

So we know that an `enum` will output the "name" of the `enum` via it's `toString` method.

This is good to know, as you can make your `enum`s descriptive.

If this isn't good enough (there's no support for spaces, or you want something a little more friendly), you could do something like...

```
public enum CRITTER_TYPE {
    CT_HERBIVORE("Herbivore"),
    CT_CARNIVORE("Carnivore");

    private String description;
    private CRITTER_TYPE(String desc) {
        description = desc;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (CRITTER_TYPE type : CRITTER_TYPE.values()) {
        System.out.println(type.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
Herbivore
Carnivore
```

`enum` in Java is a special type of object, you might like to have a read through [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for some more information

Comment: I read that page earlier today but I did not find it particularly useful to be honest. Google has failed me on this one.

Comment: So the `public enum Planet` example didn't trigger something, cause that's all we've demonstrated here.

Comment: I'm not used to using enums as classes so I didn't think of using it this way. No need to be a jerk about it.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't meant as a grip, more a surprise, my apologies if I offended, `enums` still do me head in to :P

Comment: No worries. A little bit of misunderstanding that's all !